# How to use one Google Analytics property tracking code to track multiple domains

Tags: google-analytics

I have a SaaS solution with multiple tenants, like a website builder. I want to be able track stuff like page views, visitors, and number of online users ... **for ALL of these tenants in one place**. I think Google Analytics covers a scenario like this, but I am not sure how to implement it.

Some tenants has domains, other has sub-domains:

- tenant1.app.com
- tenant2.app.com
- tenant3.com
- tenant4.com

I am trying to use one Google Analytics property to cover all of these domain, what is the correct tracking code that can accomplish that? Here is what I got so far, but I am sure it doesn't work correctly, and I probably mixing gtag.js with analytics.js (I think)

```
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=[account id]"></script>
    <script>
        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', '[account id]']);
        _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', '<?= getTenant()->getDomain() ?>']);
        _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
        gtag('js', new Date());
        gtag('config', '[account id]');
    </script>
```

PS: **No traffic is shared between these tenants**, visitors do not go from domain X to domain Y. So I am not sure *cross-domain* tracking is the solution here, since it deals with visitors crossing between different domain. I just want the total numbers for all these tenants.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing `gtag.js` code and `ga.js` (Classic Analytics) code.

Classic Analytics has been **deprecated** for some years already.

You can measure activity across domains with `gtag.js`: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/cross-domain

Or with `analytics.js` (Universal Analytics): https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cross-domain

Or more simple using `Google Tag Manager` with Universal Analytics tag: https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6164469?hl=en

Any guide you use **is important**, for the correct functioning of cross-domain tracking, **that these characteristics/results are respected**:

- All domains included in cross-domain tracking must collect data to the **same Google Analytics Property**
- All domains that are the source of cross-domain traffic, i.e. the traffic departs from these domains, need to be in the **Referral Exclusion List** of the Google Analytics Property settings
- When entering the target domain via a link in the source domain or an iframe, the URL of the page loaded in the web browser must have the _ga=1.234567.234567.234567 URL **query parameter in place**
- Any Google Analytics trackers or tags firing on the target domain need to have the **allowLinker field set to true**

More details and how to implement cross-domain tracking via GTM you can follow this article by Simo Ahava: https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/troubleshooting-cross-domain-tracking-in-google-analytics/

Comment: Great, but in fact no traffic actually passes between these domain! These are accounts for separate companies or entities, and no user from X goes to Y.

Comment: Ok, in this case it makes no sense to talk about cross domain implementation. It would be like 'buying' something you don't need.